# How can I manage the dimansions of #homeSub in CSS so it won't diappear when I move my mouse from homeBox to homeSub?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, toggle

when I hover over `#homeBox`, `#homeSub` appears. But when I want to move my mouse to click on `#homeSub` it disappears. I know that it should naturally appear and  disappear as a toggle effect but I need to fix the position so `#homeSub` will only disappear when I move the mouse out of both `#homeBox` and `#homeSub`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#homeBox").hover(function() {
    $("#homeSub").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#homeSub {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a id="homeBox" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="homeSub" href="#">you</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have posted an answer is it helpful. ?

Comment: Yes A.J totally ! I appreciate it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach hover event to ul:

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li><a id="homeBox" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="homeSub" href="#">you</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("ul#list").hover(function() {
    $("#homeSub").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```